# Deleting a record from a different model

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the models: sales and follow. The table follow has an id, an user_id and sale_id.
What I want to do is: on the sales_controller I need to find one follow record that has the user_id that is Authenticated and the sale_id that is passed as parameter.

So here is what I've tried:

Attempt 1,

```
App::import('model','Follow');
$follow = new Follow();
$follow->user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
$follow->sale_id = $id;
$follow->delete();
```

Attempt 2,

```
App::import('model','Follow');
$follow = new Follow();
$follow->delete(array('Follow.user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id'), 'Follow.sale_id'=>$id));
```

Attempt 3,

```
App::import('model','Follow');
$follow = new Follow();
$result = $follow->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Follow.user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id'), 'Follow.sale_id'=>$id)));
$result->delete()
```

Attempt 4,

```
 var $uses = array('Sale', 'Follow');
 (...)
 $result = $this->Follow->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Follow.user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id'), 'Follow.sale_id'=>$id)));
 $result->delete();
```

In attempt 3 and 4 `$result` does return the value I was expecting, but delete doesn't work.

But none of these attempts worked out.

Comment: Can't you first fetch the records that match your criteria (instead of creating a new `Follow` object) and then just call `delete()` on it? Not the most effective of ways, but that's how Active Record seems to work...

Comment: But can i do $this->Follow after I do App::Import? I've tried do the find: $this->Follow->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Follow.user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id'), 'Follow.sale_id'=>$id))) but it didn't returned any results... Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in the controller:

```
    var $uses = array('MyOriginalModelName', 'Follow');
```

Then `$this->Follow` will work.
And also It seems to be logical to add into the controller's "uses" list if you actually want to delete from it

On a side note you may want to check out the [`loadModel()` function](http://book.cakephp.org/view/845/loadModel).

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be a better way to work that with the App::Import. I can already find the record I want to delete and store it in $result.
$result = $this->Follow->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Follow.user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id'), 'Follow.sale_id'=>$id)));
But "$result->delete()" still doesn't work :S. And I can't find out why. Shouldn't I use find method?

Comment: $result->delete() makes no sense to me...
$this->follow->delete($result) if you want to go on that way :)

Comment: hmm, ok, not really, I was a bit hasty:) so  $this->Follow->delete($result['Follow']['id']); to be exact

Comment: Thank you, that's it! I'm still quite newbie @ Cakephp so I had no idea what was wrong with the delete :P. Once again, thank you for the fast response.

Comment: Np mate. All you need is the model (which you can get with the loadModel() function if you are in an another model, or don't want to set the $uses array for some reason) and the id of the record - so find() is only necessary if you don't know the exact id you want to delete